# How do I convert msecs to time string in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to convert msecs to date time string in android java code, for example:

```
    msecs = 60*60*1000;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(msecs * 1L));
```

But the result is 19:00:00, when I want the output to be 1:00:00.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set timezone to "GMT", something like:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
public class Dater {


    public static void main(String[] argv) {
       int msecs = 60*60*1000;
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
       formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
       String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(msecs * 1L));      
       System.out.println(dateString);
    }
}
```